# Foreign Launguge from MySQL showing up as ?'s in my PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that is in a foreign language. Whats pull from the MySQL db displays as ?'s where the hard coded words are showing properly. In the DB the word are displayed properly too.

I added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` to the head tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the type of that specific column?

Comment: What charset is your database set to and what is the charset of the html output?

Comment: Considering this and some of your previous questions, you seem to have fundamental lack of understanding on how character encoding works. I would **highly** recommend you read this article (as a starting point): http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: I think your answer is a co-op out! 
Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your databnase should be in UTF-8  (You can check it in PHPMyAdmin)
Your connection should be in UTF-8      (before any query: `SET NAMES utf-8` or default somewhere in settings)
Your meta-tag should be UTF-8 (Done)

Comment: All three of those conditions are met!

Comment: I'm a dumb A@@ I didn't set the connection string as UTF.. My bad and thx for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

try to run

```
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

before any DB requests

Comment: where would I put that command? in the PHP file before I run my query?

Comment: you just run it as an sql query .. before other query's, just run first ``SET NAMES 'utf8'`` then your other sql query's

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use utf8.
You have to write your PHP files in utf8 (use an editor that support it), then on your website use this line on the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

So you notice the user browser that you are using utf-8
This should allow words to be displayed correctly